# php zip один файл

Tags: php, zip

Есть несколько архивов на сервере по 500+ мб, в каждом лежит файл xml, который необходимо достать. Как, не извлекая весь архив, с помощью php, достать данные файлы?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.zip.php

Comment: Поясните ваши условия. Из вашей формулировки у меня сложилось впечатление, что вы хотите не доставать файлы не распаковывая архив.